# Finding critical connections (bridges) in an undirected graph. Isn't my approach linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, edges

I know Tarjan algorithm solves the problem of finding bridges (cut-edges) in a graph in linear time. I am trying to solve the problem in a slightly different manner. I try to find all edges which are part of a cycle. To do this I use a parent array such as  `parent[i]=j`. Here `j` is parent of `i` because call to `dfs(i)` was made inside/from `dfs(j)`. I also maintain a set of visited and visiting nodes. Every time a back-edge is found, I just traverse through the parent array to find all edges belonging to that cycle and dump these edges into a set (say `cycle_edges`). Now all edges that aren't inside `cycle_edges` are bridges. The algorithm shows TLE in Leetcode OJ for large inputs. On the face of it, the algorithm looks linear time  some `O(V+nE)`. Is it that if I have way too many cycles in my graph with some edges belonging to multiple cycles, I traverse back using parent array every time,increasing `n`  and making it too high ? You can find code snippet of my `dfs` function below. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with time complexity of this particular solution. Thank You!

```
    void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& graph, int current_node, vector<int>& parent, unordered_set<int>& visiting, unordered_set<int>& visited, unordered_set<pair<int, int>, PairHash>& cycle_edges){

        visiting.insert(current_node);
        //cout << "Current node: " << current_node << endl; 
        for (auto neighbor: graph[current_node])
        {
          if (visiting.find(neighbor) == visiting.end() && visited.find(neighbor) == visited.end()){
            parent[neighbor] = current_node;
            dfs(graph, neighbor, parent, visiting, visited, cycle_edges);
          }
          else if(visiting.find(neighbor) != visiting.end() && visited.find(neighbor) == visited.end()){
            if (parent[current_node] != neighbor){
              //found a back edge
              //cout << "Found a back edge" << endl;
              if (neighbor > current_node){
                cycle_edges.insert({current_node, neighbor});
                //cout << current_node << " " << neighbor << endl;
              }
              else{
                cycle_edges.insert({neighbor, current_node});
                //cout << neighbor << " " << current_node << endl;
              }

              int node_first = current_node;
              int node_second = parent[current_node];

              while (node_first != neighbor){
                if (node_first > node_second){
                  cycle_edges.insert({node_second, node_first});
                  //cout << node_second << " " << node_first << endl;
                }
                else{
                  cycle_edges.insert({node_first, node_second});
                  //cout << node_first << " " << node_second << endl;
                }
                node_first = node_second;
                node_second = parent[node_second];
              }
            }
          }
        }
        visiting.erase(current_node);
        visited.insert(current_node);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code as formatted text, not image. Otherwise it is hard to read and hard to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Zabuza . I have provided my code as formatted text now.

Comment: As a side-note, it's probably better to use `map<pair<int, int>>` than your own pair hash. I've run some tests on my own at some point, and I'm pretty sure `map<pair<int, int>>` outperformed most hash functions I tested on `pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Thanks @EkeshKumar for the comment. Do you mean to say hash<pair<int, int>> ? I don't think C++ defines hashing functions for pairs of primitive data types.

Comment: Your algorithm sounds like it works, but it takes O(|V|*|E|) time -- not linear

Comment: C++ doesn't have hashing for pairs of primitive data type. I am suggesting you use map, which is implemented with a balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

The code works in O(V+E) but some minor optimisations can be made.

`vector<int> visiting(n,0),visited(n,0);` can be used instead of a set to track record of visiting and visited nodes.

`unordered_set<>` has a Hashing function behind it and often includes large constant time complexities.

Using a `vector<set<int>>(n,unordered_set<int>())` instead may be better.

If you query every edge to find if it exists in `cycle_edges` then it takes `|E| * find_complexity` time.

You can break each edge into a lower-numbered vertex which will point to the set that we need to search for its higher-numbered neighbour.

If you can provide a link to the question, maybe a better approach can be found.